# Building Python Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm writing a function for reading a determinate file, this case, the user can choose the file that he wants read.

```
import os
import pprint as p

path = "C:\Users\cgr02\Documents\Py"
listname = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
 for filename in files:
  if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
   ob = listanome.setdefault(filename, dict({'FILE': filename}))

p.pprint (listname)
```

Output:

```
 '19-10-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '19-10-2017.xlsx'},
 '19-11-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '19-11-2017.xlsx'},
 '20-06-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '20-06-2017.xlsx'},
 '20-07-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '20-07-2017.xlsx'},
 '20-08-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '20-08-2017.xlsx'},
 '20-09-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '20-09-2017.xlsx'},
 '20-10-2017.xlsx': {'FILE': '20-10-2017.xlsx'},
```

What the user expect to see:

```
'1': {'File': '20-10-2017.xlsx'},
'2': {'File': '20-09-2017.xlsx'},
'3': {'File': '20-08-2017.xlsx'},
'4': {'File': '20-12-2017.xlsx'},
'5': {'File': '20-11-2017.xlsx'},
```

I dont know if this is the better way to show on screen and manipulate the user' s choice. Would be better using a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could simply use a list. Using a list comprehension could also make this a bit more straightforward than using `dict.setdefault`.

For example:

```
import os
path = ...
files = [filename for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) 
         for filename in files 
         if filename.endswith(".xlsx")]
```

and then use `enumerate` and `print` instead of `pprint`:

```
for idx, file in enumerate(files, 1):  # enumeration, starting with 1 instead of 0
    print(idx, file)
```

Note that you *probably* should store the `root` and `dirs` in case you actually need find the "selected" file(s) again.

Comment: This is great, didn't know about it, but how I add it to a dict? "append"?

Comment: The solutions doesn't use any dicts, which dict would you like to keep?

Comment: For example, how would I recover the filename chose by user? In my idea, by the idx I could get the filename+path.. What do you think?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want. Does a user enter a filename or a number? If it's a number, just convert that number to an `int`, subtract 1 and then index the list with that number. That should return the corresponding filename (without path, except you store the filename + path in the list instead of just the filename).

Comment: Yes, is that! Thanks